# error: The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'String'. dart flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

This is my code.( A detail page for json api response) I'm trying to make color red if negative, and green if positive. My code is :

```html
class StocksDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  final String? degisimoran;
  final String? sondeger;
  final String? hacim;
  final String? mindeger;
  final String? maxdeger;
  final String? hisseismi;
  final String? hissekodu;



  const StocksDetailScreen({
    Key? key,
    this.degisimoran,
     this.sondeger,
     this.hacim,
     this.mindeger,
     this.maxdeger,
     this.hisseismi,
     this.hissekodu,


  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StocksDetailScreen> createState() => _StocksDetailScreenState();
}

class _StocksDetailScreenState extends State<StocksDetailScreen> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.hisseismi!,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),),

        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          bottom: true,
          top: false,
          maintainBottomViewPadding: true,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[

                          Divider(height: 3.6,),
                          SizedBox(height: 50,),
                          Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                FadeInUp(
                                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                  from: 30,
                                  child: Text(
                                    widget.sondeger!,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: widget.sondeger! > 0
                                        ? Colors.green
                                        : Colors.red,
                                        fontSize: 36,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
...
```

On the line:

```html
                                  child: Text(
                                    widget.sondeger!,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: widget.sondeger! > 0
                                        ? Colors.green
                                        : Colors.red,
                                        fontSize: 36,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

I get this error. error: The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'String'. dart flutter. How can i fix this? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `final String? sondeger;` as String, it cant have smaller or greater condition like this. You may int as parameter to access the pass number.

```dart
  final int? sondeger;
```

```dart
Text(
  "${widget.sondeger}",
  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
    textStyle: TextStyle(
      color: (widget.sondeger??0) > 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
      fontSize: 36,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
);
```

To receive string follow selimdogan

Comment: In the previous page im sending data to this screen with this: StocksDetailScreen(
                        degisimoran: hisseResult?.result[index].rate??"",...
so that im now getting this error : error: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int?'.

Comment: do `degisimoran: hisseResult?.result[index].rate??0`

Comment: Now i converted it to this: degisimoran: hisseResult?.result[index].rate!.toInt(),

Comment: One last error: The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.  at the color: (widget.sondeger??0) > 0
                                          ? Colors.green
                                          : Colors.red,

Comment: did you changed to `final int? sondeger;`

Comment: yes, by the way I'm working on "degisimoran" not "sondeger"

Comment: Sorry, my bad, error is gone now Checking the result

Comment: if it is integer, do the same for it. `final int? degisimoran;`

Comment: For future comment readers: Other method doesn't recognize the value as a number and can't change the color. This way works.

Comment: this method doesn't show the decimal numbers. how can i make it show decimal numbers? If the value is 0.92 it shows it as 0

Comment: replace int with double like `final double? degisimoran`

Answer (score 1):

Hi your variable is a string and in dart you can't do it. Before that you need convert string to integer.

```
final String? sondeger;
```

In dart you can convert like that.

```
int.parse(sondeger)>0
```

But this variable is nullable and if you are not sure about this variable can be not number. I suggest you to use

```
int.tryParse(var);
```

[More information](https://dev.to/wangonya/how-you-turn-a-string-into-a-number-or-vice-versa-with-dart-392h)

Comment: Error is gone but its red both at negative and positive value.

Answer (score 1):

You have the variable `sondeger` defined as `String?`.

So, you have to parse the String variable into int and compare it.

Example

```
child: Text(
   widget.sondeger!,
   style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
   textStyle: TextStyle(
         color: (int.tryParse("${widget.sondeger}") ?? 0) > 0
                 ? Colors.green
                  : Colors.red,
         fontSize: 36,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
       ),
     ),
 ),
```

It tries to parse the given string into int; if failed, defaults to 0.

[image]

Comment: Error is gone but its red both at negative and positive value

Comment: can you check what value you are getting in `(int.tryParse("${widget.sondeger}") ?? 0)` ?  Updated the answer with the dartpad example